# I'm getting this error nuget package restore failed for project

Tags: c#, nuget, telerik, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I cloned project from git that I need, and I fixed all errors and now I want to build project but I'm getting this error NuGet Package restore failed for project: Unable to find version '2013.2.611' of package 'TelerikMvcExtensions'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages: Package 'TelerikMvcExtensions.2013.2.611' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages'.
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'TelerikMvcExtensions.2013.2.611' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/: Package 'TelerikMvcExtensions.2013.2.611' is not found on source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/'.

---

### UPDATE

---

NuGet Package restore failed for project: Unable to find version '0.5.0' of package 'TelerikMvcGridCustomBindingHelper'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages: Package 'TelerikMvcGridCustomBindingHelper.0.5.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages'.
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/: Package 'TelerikMvcGridCustomBindingHelper.0.5.0' is not found on source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/'.
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'TelerikMvcGridCustomBindingHelper.0.5.0' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json.
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.

What should I do?

I added in Tools-Packet Manager-Package Source, and I clicked plus button and made with this source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ and with this https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json but nothing happened

### ****UPDATE SOLVED****

I had to delete those files from packages.config XML

Comment: Did you try to clear the Nuget cache? Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Settings->Clear All Nuget Cache

Comment: @d4zed yes, nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search shows you need to add Telerik as a package source:

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings, select Package Manager Sources, and then click the + button.
3. Enter a Name for the Telerik NuGet feed, for example, telerik.com.
4. In the Source field, enter https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json and click OK.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/installation/nuget-install).

**UPDATE:**

It looks like this version has been deprecated. Others have run into the same issue and made the DLLs available for download [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/telerik-asp-net-(old)-documentation). Just get whatever DLLs are needed and manually reference them in your project.

I strongly suggest you exercise caution when downloading files from the internet. Make sure to verify their authenticity and scan for viruses.

Comment: Thank you, now I get this one
Error  NuGet Package restore failed for project: Unable to find version '0.5.0' of package 'TelerikMvcGridCustomBindingHelper'.
  https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json.

Comment: Taking a second look, it looks like you need to have an account and/or license to use this. Did you restart VS? It should prompt you for credentials.

Comment: It's worse than that. It seems this version was deprecated. That is why you can't find it.

Comment: Yes it popup for credentials but still can't run the project getting that error

Comment: @LeonRaicevic I just updated my answer. Read the update at the bottom.

Comment: still getting error, I updated my error

Comment: @LeonRaicevic Bottom line is you are using a deprecated library and it's no longer available as a Nuget  package. Check the GIT repository. Maybe they added it in there somewhere for posterity. Otherwise, you will have to go find these DLLs somewhere online. There is no other way.

Comment: I checked they didn't add it, I hate this when I can't start project